# Batch: Remove linefeed from variable containing first line of file

Tags: batch-file, io, compare

I have a variable containing an ID. This ID I want to write into a file and later retrieve it for further processing. Other stuff can be written to the file afterwards, thus I use the `/P` to retrieve only the first line.

```
SET ID=%RANDOM%
ECHO %ID% >> my_file.txt

SET /P LINE=< my_file.txt
ECHO %ID%==%LINE%?
IF "%ID%" == "%LINE%" (
    ECHO Equal!
) ELSE (
    ECHO Not equal!
)
```

Output:

> 15770==15770 ?
>   Not equal

I noticed the *blank* character before the question mark. My thought was that it was the `linefeed`, so I extended my script to:

```
SET ID=%RANDOM%
ECHO %ID% >> my_file.txt

SET /P LINE=< my_file.txt

REM Try to remove the linefeed.
SET LINE2=%LINE:~0,-1% 
ECHO %ID%==%LINE2%?
IF "%ID%" == "%LINE2%" (
    ECHO Equal!
) ELSE (
    ECHO Not equal!
)
```

Output:

> 16332==16332 ?
>   Not equal

I still get a *blank* character, but remove two characters from the raw input, removes one of the digits.

**How can I convert the input from the first line in `my_file.txt` so I get a value I can compare to the original value I wrote to the file?**

Comment: also note that `==` does a string comparison. Use `EQU` instead.

Comment: In my example I do use string comparison - to ensure a common data type. But as @Magoo suggest I could do a clean numeric comparison instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use this format then there is no need for a trailing character
and there will not be a linefeed in normal use:

```
>>my_file.txt ECHO %ID%
```

When you use this there is a space after the variable contents, which is often used because a single digit like 1 before a redirection character will fail to echo the numeral.

```
ECHO %ID% >> my_file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always use

```
set /a line=%line%
```

to remove any stray spaces, leadng or trailing, if you are sure the data read is numeric.

Comment: I really like this idea and I will probably use it. I have given @foxidrive the accept because I think its more generic.